# Can I use python 2.6 with ArcGIS 9.3?

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3

Is it possible to use Python 2.6 (or 2.7?) with ArcGIS 9.3?

The official stance is no, [not supported](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=31912). There are a number of reports in the wild though that it can be done. How is this accomplished? and is there anything to watch out for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all ArcGIS 9 versions you can upgrade python to the latest and greatest version with a few simple steps. Here's the recipe for 9.3 and 2.6:

- Install python 2.6, and the latest corresponding [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).
- Grab the *arcgisscripting.py* script written by Philippe Le Grand (see [this thread](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1729&t=216040#667051) in the ESRI scripting forum) and plop it into `C:\Python2.6\Lib\site-packages`
- Make sure PYTHONPATH environment variable points to `C:\path\to\ArcGIS\bin`

This is an unsupported configuration, see [ESRI knowledgebase article 31912](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=31912).

Recipe from http://www.yukongis.ca/How_To/Upgrading_ArcGIS_Python

Comment: All is not *completely* well though, I recently discovered that `gp.ListDatasets()` breaks in py2.6 with ["This object does not support enumeration"](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3076741&group_id=78018&atid=551954)

Comment: The issue `gp.ListDatasets()` has something to do with arcgis [changing from enumerators to lists](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Differences_between_geoprocessor_versions), also [see this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_the_geoprocessor_object&anchor=comparing_93_and_92_geoprocessors) in 9.2 to 9.3 for some methods. Not sure why this didn't become an issue at this point, when it didn't surface with py2.5 and 9.3. See (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10922/enumeration-problem-with-eclipse-and-arcgis-9-3) for solution

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any compelling reason to upgrade beyond 'because I want to?' Most popular third-party Python libraries are available for 2.5 and there's no point in risking major compatibility issues. `arcgisscripting` should fail and throw with an error like "use of python25.DLL conflicts with this version of Python" when importing a 9.3.X arcgisscripting in Python 2.6 or beyond.

Comment: The main impetus is that my text editor / IDE of choice, [leo-editor](http://webpages.charter.net/edreamleo/front.html), requires 2.6+. I've not encountered the dll conflict message and I've been upgrading beyond the ESRI shipped python since py2.1 (using the recipe in the other answer). However it should be noted I only use a small subset of the geoprocessing tools and there may well be incompatibilities yet to be uncovered.