# import arcpy yields "TypeError: This object does not support enumeration"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, typeerror

Similar to [Enumeration Problem with Eclipse and arcgisscripting?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10922/enumeration-problem-with-eclipse-and-arcgis-9-3), with Arcgis v10 I no longer seem to be able to run python scripts from a command shell. Entering the same code into an interactive python console *from the same shell* does work! Other scripts I have from a few months ago seem to work fine. I don't get it.

This works:

```
d:\s>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.env.workspace = 'd:/'
>>> print arcpy.env.workspace
d:/
>>>
```

Create a minimal test file:

```
d:\s>copy con d:\code\arcgis\test-arcpy.py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'd:/'
print "Workspace is: ", arcpy.env.workspace^Z
        1 file(s) copied.
```

and give it a spin:

```
d:\s>python d:\code\arcgis\test-arcpy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\code\arcgis\test-arcpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 568, in <module>
    env = GPEnvironments(gp)
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 565, in GPEnvironments
    return GPEnvironment(geoprocessor)
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 521, in __init__
    self._refresh()
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 523, in _refresh
    envset = (set(env for env in self._gp.listEnvironments()))
  File "C:\ESRI\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 523, in <genexpr>
    envset = (set(env for env in self._gp.listEnvironments()))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 246, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError("This object does not support enumeration")
TypeError: This object does not support enumeration
```

**update** it's directory specific! If I copy that same `test-arcpy.py` file somewhere else it works.

Comment: Do you have two copies of Python installed? I had weird problems associated with PythonX,Y (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/installing-arcgis-10-with-pythonx-y) which were resolved when I installed ArcGIS 10 without the built-in python package.

Comment: found it @Jason, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aahhhh, found it! I ran afoul of keeping scripts I wrote for Arcgis 9 and 10 in the same directory. Something about the initialization logic in `import arcpy` finds the custom `arcgisscripting.py` used for running [python 2.6 with arcgis 9.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2227/108) when they are located together.

So as long as I keep them separated all is copacetic. I didn't run into this earlier because my other v10 scripts are part of a v10 specific project stored in a different spot.