# Why can't I import arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, importerror

```
>>> import arcpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\arcpy\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\Python27\lib\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This is the error I get when i try to import arcpy. Any suggestions?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 7):

In Arcmap open the python a.k.a. command line window, under *Geoprocessing* in 10.1, type `import os`, and then `os.__file__` to deduce the location of python.exe (recipe found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749711/how-to-get-the-python-exe-location-programmatically/8187027#8187027)).  Use the results of that to fine tune the PYTHONPATH environment variable in whatever command shell or IDE you're using.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.__file__
'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.1\\Lib\\os.pyc'
```

so python.exe, and thus PYTHONHOME is one level up, `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1`.

Here's my batch file to enable ArcGIS python in a standard Windows Command Prompt shell:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo.   Setting environment for ArcGIS python 2.7
echo.
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONHOME%\Lib;%PYTHONHOME%\DLLs
set PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts;%path%
set py
python --version
```

Answer (score 4):

i'm not sure why your arcpy has been copied to c:\python27\lib. The standard install location is inside ArcGIS\desktop10.x or equivalent for other products.

**approach to fix #1** : dodge stray arcpy package. 
if there is a arcpy folder in the product install directory (eg. c:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.x.) it could just be hitting this stray arcpy folder first.  You can rename c:\python27\lib\arcpy to c:\python27\lib\arcpy2  then import arcpy will miss this stray and (hopefully) hit the real arcpy package

**approach to fix #2** : make stray arcpy package find arcgisscripting. 
The error is "can't find arcgisscripting" which is a pyd file inside the arcgis "bin" folder.

Easiest way to add it is to create a text file called something.pth inside c:\python27\lib\site-packages

into this file, put 2 paths
C:\Program files (x86)\desktop10.2\bin
C:\Program files (x86)\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts

the second path certain gp tools rely on (inside the Spatial Stats library).

Comment: The above copy/paste was from PythonWIN. I reinstalled Python into my ArcGIS directory. I followed your approach #2, opened PythonIDLE and this is the message I get now.

Comment: >>> import arcpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
ImportError: No module named arcpy

Comment: ok, you do have some arcgis product installed (yes?) and in product install dir there is a folder named 'arcpy' yes? if yes, then create a .pth as per approach #2 above, and set 3 paths in it #1 path to arcgis\bin, #2 path to arcgis\arcpy #3 path to arcgis\arctoolbox\scripts

Comment: Also see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27058/issues-importing-arcpy-in-python-idle

Answer (score -1):

It's better to [check the GIS wiki](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Python) to help you in this case. In different versions of ArcGIS we need to use different modules. From the wiki:

> Python support in different versions of ArcGIS
>
> The geoprocessor python object is accessed differently depending on the version of ArcGIS:
>   [edit] ArcGIS 9.0/9.1
>
> These versions of ArcGIS use Python 2.1 with the PythonWin[6] package to access a >Geoprocessor using a COM interface:
>
> import win32com # PythonWin
>   gp = win32com.client.Dispatch("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")
>
> The GpDispatch COM interface is available in later versions of ArcGIS, though it is only >available to Python if PythonWin is installed. [7] GpDispatch provides access to >geoprocessing using any language that supports COM.
>   [edit] ArcGIS 9.2
>
> This version of ArcGIS uses Python 2.4 and brought a major change to how the Geoprocessor >was created. The win32com.client is no longer needed, replaced by the Python-native >(non-COM) arcgisscripting module. This both provides better performance and allows >platform independence; Python geoprocessing scripts using the arcgisscripting module are >supported on non-Windows versions of ArcGIS Server.
>
> import arcgisscripting
>   gp = arcgisscripting.create()
>
> [edit] ArcGIS 9.3/9.3.1
>
> These versions of ArcGIS use Python 2.5.1 and can be used with both the 9.3 version of >arcgisscripting or the original 9.2 version of arcgisscripting.
>
> import arcgisscripting
>   gp = arcgisscripting.create() # 9.2 (default for ArcGIS 9.2,9.3)
>   gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3) # 9.3
>
> You can determine the version of the geoprocessor from its ScriptVersion property:
>
> print "GP version: " + str(gp.ScriptVersion)
>
> [edit] ArcGIS 10
>
> This version of ArcGIS adds the new arcpy module. ArcPy is a site-package that builds on (and is a successor to) the arcgisscripting module. Its goal is to create the corner-stone for a useful and productive way to perform data analysis, data conversion, data management, and map automation with Python.
>
> import arcpy
>
> The older versions of the geoprocessor (GpDispatch and the arcgisscripting module) are still supported to allow for forward compatibility of Python scripts.