# Importing ArcPy in PyCharm?

Tags: arcpy, installation, pycharm

```
>>> import arcpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS10.5\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS10.5\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS10.5\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import arcgisscripting
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What does it mean?

By the way,I have downloaded python 3.7 for studying, which means I may have two python interpreter in my system.

Is it the reason I can't import arcpy?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify which python interpreter you have set in `File->Settings->Project Interpreter` and if it's different to the interpreter in the `Run->Edit Configurations...` for your script.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, although the symptoms are the same, and the answers to [Why can't I import arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55506/why-cant-i-import-arcpy) are completely irrelevant to PyCharm.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/setting-up-pycharm-to-reference-arcpy

Answer (score 1):

Set your python interpreter in `File->Settings->Project Interpreter` to `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\python.exe` and you may need to change the run/debug interpreter for your script in `Run->Edit Configurations...` to the same `python.exe`.